# MATLAB - solving the integral with bessel function

Tags: matlab, integral

I'm trying to solve the integral of variable x (from 0 to Inf) which is the function of variable S. I want to solve this integral and find the vector of results dependent on variable S. [integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVb8K.png)

I want to then approximate this function by polyfit (to have a function E(S))

> ```
> nu=0; int_val=zeros([255,1]); for i=1:10
> S=i/100;
> %besselj(0,S*2)
> fun = @(x)log(abs(x-(pi/2)^2.*(-S.^2/2))).*x.*exp((x.^2+S.^2)/2).*besselj(nu,S.*x);
> int_val(i) = integral(fun,0,Inf); end
> ```

Unfortunately, the MATBAL calculates only NaN number. It isvery important for me.. Please, help.

Comment: Is it possible that it should be `.* besselj` instead of `*besselj`?

Comment: Have you double-checked that the function you define in `fun` is really the integrand you want to evaluate? It seems that the function is growing to really large numbers for large x, so the integral cannot converge.

Comment: The formula in the screenshot is not really a valid expression. What is S(x)? What is the argument of the log (only the x?)?

Comment: So, as a general hint, whenever you want to integrate a function numerically and face some kind of trouble, do plot the integrand as a function of x and see if it is what you expected ...

Comment: Another comment: The symbol I_0 is frequently used for the modified bessel function instead of the usual bessel function, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1). Maybe you confused the kind of Bessel function?

Answer (score 0):

As I have already written in the comments, your integrand function is growing to infinity for large x. Therefore, the integral cannot converge.

The following code

```
nu=0; 
int_val=zeros([255,1]); 
i = 1;
S=i/100;
fun = @(x)log(abs(x-(pi/2)^2.*(-S.^2/2))).*x.*exp((x.^2+S.^2)/2).*besselj(nu,S.*x);
x = 0:0.1:100;
semilogy(x, fun(x))
```

results in this plot:

[image]

You cannot integrate a function like that from 0 to infinity, as the result does not converge to a finite number.

In your above answer, you state that S(x) depends on x. However, in your code S is a constant. Maybe that is the problem - if you replace S by an actual function of x that goes to zero for x to infinity, you might end up with a converging integral.